# Keeping a copy of a vector value, which will then be over-written

Tags: c++

I have some code which is like follows:

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass();
vector[0] = *a;

MyClass KeepCopy = vector[0];

//
//
vector gets changed
//
//

return KeepCopy
```

Now vector then goes and does lots of stuff and gets overridden. However, I wish to return the value of KeepCopy at the end of my function. However, because vector[0] is no pointing to something else I think I am being returned the wrong data.

EDIT3: Ok so this is whats happening. KeepCopy gets assigned to vector[0] and then in the code I do stuff to vector[0]. I was thinking that KeepCopy still points to a version of vector[0], but it appears KeepCopy only contains a copy of the value AT THE TIME which the assignment was made.

Later on I assign vector to another vector object (I am reading a text file two lines at a time, vector contains one line and this other vector object contains the second line). How can I make sure KeepCopy points to the original vector[0] element (before I start parsing through each line in the textfile, reassigning the vectors)?

Comment: Do you have a proper copy constructor for `MyClass`?

Comment: Why do you use 'new' to create the object? Do you remember to delete it or do you just leak memory? C++ is not Java or C#

Comment: @Jonathan. In the end I returned *a. However a general question, where should I do this deletion? Should it be after the code where I return *a to? As in, the end of the program (its a simple console app)?

Comment: If you return *a then you return a **copy** of the object and leak the original. Just don't use 'new' then you don't need to delete anything. C++ is not Java, you don't need to use new to create objects. Variables in C++ are values not references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are storing the object by value (and not by pointer/referenence), changes to `vector[0]` are not reflected in `KeepCopy`, unless you share pointers to the same contained object in `MyClass` instances

If this is the case, you should implement a proper copy constructor that makes a deep copy of the original (instead of the default shallow copy that just blindly copies the values of pointers)

Comment: I don't believe I do share pointers. Would I be able to just return *a?

Comment: @user997112 - If you are positive that you don't share pointers (and none of the member variables do either), then you can return `*a` or `KeepCopy`.

Comment: Hi, I have modified my post above which should help you understand what I am doing.

Comment: `vector<>` stores elements by value, so you need to store pointers to your `MyClass` objects, not the objects themselves.  Then changes to the elements in the vector (via the pointers) will reflect in the objects the pointers point to.

Comment: yup I concluded that! I ended up changing all my vectors to be pointers and the vector contained within MyClass also contained points. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Implement a copy constructor for MyClass and copy the object. Not the pointer.

Comment: True, i am assuming he meant that he is also overwriting the data later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you did it: `MyClass KeepCopy = vector[0];` will set `KeepCopy` to a copy of the original object (via its copy constructor). This copy has no connection to the vector, so it won't be affected by modifying the vector.

Comment: You're right, that needs to be done properly in the class' copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the following steps happen in your function

1. You do some things with vector[0] that modify it.
2. You reassign the whole vector.

And the state of vector[0] after step 1, but before step 2, is the thing you want to return.  So that's the point in your code where you should make the copy.

```
MyClass foo()
{
    //
    // some stuff
    //

    MyClass* a = new MyClass();
    vector[0] = *a;

    //
    // vector[0] gets modified
    //

    // you want vector[0]'s value here, so this is where you should create the copy
    MyClass KeepCopy = vector[0];


    //
    // Whole vector gets reassigned
    //

    return KeepCopy
}
```